Function field over a perfect field can be generated by two elements
I have two questions about the following theorem:
Theorem: Let $K$ be a perfect field, $F$ a function field in one variable over $K$ (i.e., a finite algebraic extension of $K(t)$). Then there is $x \in F$ such that $F$ is finite and separable over $K(x)$.
A corollary of the above theorem and the primitive element theorem is:
Corollary: Any function field in one variable over a perfect field can be generated by two elements.
$$\underline{\qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad}$$
Below, I'll write down a proof of the above theorem, which is also found here for $K = \mathbb F_p$.
Questions:

Is the hypothesis that $K$ is perfect really needed for the Theorem or the corollary? (I'll indicate where it is used in the proof below.) I've seen several sources (e.g. Stichenoth's book on function fields, after Remark 1.1.3) claim the corollary holds for every ground field (not only perfect ones), but I've seen no reference or proof.
There is a detail I don't understand in the proof, namely, why the polynomial $h(X)$ defined near the end is separable.

$$\underline{\qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad}$$
Proof of the Theorem: The statement is clear in characteristic $0$, so let's assume $\mathrm{char}(K) = p > 0$. Let $F' \subset F$ be a subfield satisfying the following two properties:

there is $x \in F$ such that $F'/K(x)$ is algebraic and separable,
the degree $[F:F']$ is minimal.

Obviously, the goal is to show that $F = F'$. Let us assume that $F \neq F'$. Observe that every element of $F \setminus F'$ is inseparable over $F'$, by property 2. In other words: $F/F'$ is purely inseparable. We thus find $y \in F \setminus F'$ such that $y^p \in F'$. Our main claim is that $F'(y)/K(y)$ is separable, contradicting property 2, since $[F:F'(y)] < [F:F']$.
Let
$$f(T) := T^n + a_{n-1}T^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 \in K(x)[T]$$
be the separable (!) minimal polynomial of $y^p$ over $K(x)$. By choosing $y$ appropriately, we may assume that $a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_0 \in K[x]$.
We claim that there is an index $i$ such that $a_i \notin K[x^p]$. Assume for a contradiction that $a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_0 \in K[x^p]$. Since $K$ is perfect, there are $b_i \in K[x]$ such that $b_i^p = a_i$ (since $K$ being perfect is equivalent to the Frobenius $K \to K$ being surjective). Now, let
$$g(T) := T^n + b_{n-1}T^{n-1} + \ldots + b_0 \in K(x)[T].$$
Then $g(T^{1/p})^p = f(T)$. This formula shows that $g(T)$ is irreducible, since $f$ is. Moreover, $f(y^p) = g(y) = 0$. But $f$ is separable, hence $f' \neq 0$. We obtain $g' \neq 0$, a contradiction, since then $y$ would be the root of an irreducible separable polynomial.
Thus there is at least one $i$ such that $a_i = a_i(x) \notin K[x^p]$. Consider now the polynomial
$$h(X) := y^{pn} + y^{p(n-1)}a_{n-1}(X) + \ldots + a_0(X) \in K(y)[X].$$
We have $h(x) = 0$, and since there is at least one $a_i$ which is not a polynomial in $X^p$, we obtain that $h'(X) \neq 0$.
If we could show now that $h(X)$ is irreducible, we would be done: then $x$ is separable over $K(y)$, so that we have the two separable extensions $K(x,y)/K(y)$ and $F'(y)/K(x,y)$. Then $F'(y)/K(y)$ is also separable, which is a contradiction, as explained above. $\Box$
So how do we show that $h(X)$ is irreducible? Irreducibility over $K(y^p)$ is easy, but not sufficient. Note that the implication
$$h' \neq 0 \implies h \text{ has no multiple roots}$$
is only true if $h$ is irreducible, so I think this is what we need to show. I might be missing something simpler, though.
